Pull() function: why these outputs are different?
I am trying to understand a problem regarding the pull() function using these two examples:
df <- data.frame(x = c("ex", "ex"), y = c("why", "why"))
d <- df
x <- "y"

pull(d, x)

d <- select(df, -x)

pull(d, x)
pull(d, y)

# - - - - - - 

Why does this output look like the pull() function is working well but the output before was not working?
library(dplyr)

# Using the dataframe “mtcars”
df <- mtcars

# Define a variable
x <- 'mpg'

# Using pull() to extract column "mpg"
resultado <- pull(df, x)
print(resultado)

# Remove column "mpg"
df <- select(df, -x)

# Using pull() again with variable x, which still contains "mpg"
resultado <- pull(df, x)
print(resultado)

In this second case thepull(df, x) should be different right? Not an error.
In both chunks of code I should have the same result which is a vector. But at the second code using mtcars as datframe I get this error:
Error in pull(): ! Can't extract columns that don't exist. ✖ Column mpg doesn't exist.
Considering this article: https://graphdr.github.io/data-stories/posts/2024-08-01-subtle-flaw-pull/

Which line specific are you referring to when you say "the second case"? What version of tidyselect is being used in your sessionInfo(). Running select(df, -x) should have warned you about updated syntax. It should be select(df, -any_of(x)) if you want to use a character vector.

@MrFlick I am considering this article:
https://graphdr.github.io/data-stories/posts/2024-08-01-subtle-flaw-pull/

@MrFlick I am referring the second chunck of code

select(df, -x) returns a dataframe df without column "x". In contrast, pull(df, x) returns a vector x (not a dataframe with a single column "x").

Yes, tidyselect has been update to prevent the issue, but you are using the old syntax. If you want to use a character vector of names use all_of(x) or any_of(x). You don't get errors in the first chuck because you actually have a column named x. Both pull() commands return the y values because x is ambiguous. But you can't select mpg in the final line because you removed mpg in the line before and there is no column named x. Perhaps you can translate your comments into english so it's more clear what you are trying to do
